# SAP OCI integration without SAP

Tags: http, sap-srm

Our supplier requires us to use [SAP Open Catalog Interface](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/1d/cfb65334e6b54ce10000000a174cb4/content.htm) to order goods.
However we do not have SAP, so I should implement it from scratch.

Has anyone done this and is willing to share his experience / hints on where to start etc.?

This is the [OCI doc](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SRM/OCI+Documentation?preview=/395284636/395444882/OCI%204.0%20Documentation.pdf) I follow.

Comment: Which system/language do you use? Without more details: You need a webservice who accepts a formula. The target URL of your service will be added as a hookurl in the OCI call. Then your webservice must analyze the order data from the OCI call. The order itself is outside OCI.

Comment: Thank you @knut, I use C# / .NET, but I am not limited by a system...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't help you in implementing your system (too broad and not enough information - and off topic for this  site :))

But I can give a process description to give you a start point.

Your supplier has to give you a link to the OCI-Shop (including login credentials).
You attach a parameter hookurl with your landing page to this URL.

So you get something like:

```
https://www.mysupplier.com/OCI/ocilogin?user=yourname&password=yourpassword&hookurl=https://example.net/oci_receive_from_supplier_X
```

When you call this URL, it directs you to the shop of the supplier, where you can select materials.
When you finished, you don't order, but you request the order data and the supplier sends a formula to your hookurl https://example.net/oci_receive_from_supplier_X

The formula data may look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="SUBMITFORM" action="https://example.net/oci_receive_from_supplier_X" method="post" id="SUBMITFORM">
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATNR[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY[1]" value="0000000000001"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[1]" value="article description"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDORMAT[1]" value="4711"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-PRICE[1]" value="56.95"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CURRENCY[1]" value="EUR"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-UNIT[1]" value="PCE"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LEADTIME[1]" value="5"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_1:132[]" value="article description"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDOR[1]" value="987654"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT_ITEM[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP[1]" value="12345678"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_CATEGORY_ID[1]" value="12345678"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_SCHEMA_TYPE[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD2[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD3[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD4[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD5[1]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATNR[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY[2]" value="0000000000001"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[2]" value="other article description"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDORMAT[2]" value="4712"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-PRICE[2]" value="65.07"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CURRENCY[2]" value="EUR"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-UNIT[2]" value="PCE"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LEADTIME[2]" value="5"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_2:132[]" value="other article description"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDOR[2]" value="987654"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT_ITEM[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP[2]" value="12345678"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_CATEGORY_ID[2]" value="12345678"> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_SCHEMA_TYPE[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD2[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD3[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD4[2]" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD5[2]" value="">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 document.SUBMITFORM.submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now your script has to extract the order data and you can do with it whatever you want (start an approval workflow, ...) and in the end you can order 
(however you want. You can start an EDI process, or you send an order fax...) But this order process is outside the OCI itself.

Comment: Thank you @knut, do you know if I can start the process from our system? Because I need to have an order identification in my system first.

Comment: Without knowing your system: Yes. You could create the order identification and append it as a parameter to your hook url. E.g. https://example.net/oci_receive_from_supplier_X?order_id=123456. Depending on the partner system the parameter separator & must be masked.